# "Error: permission denied" error from Transmission Client

Tags: permissions, dd-wrt, transmission

i have done the following on my Asus WL-520gu

1. Installed the dd-wrtv24-sp2 mini svn:13064
2. Updated for usb support
3. Installed optware package
4. Activated the transmission client

but i keep getting a permission error for files.
I think it is a user access thing.

How to resolve this issue? Is there any way to ignore user permissions on a drive?

**Update:**

i think it is due to the permissions of the user under which the transmission daemon is running. Can I change that user to root?

I know where but don't know how `/etc/init.d/transmission`.

[image]

Comment: Does the user you are running as have write permissions to `/mnt/data/torrents/downloads`?

Comment: I cannot parse the last sentence. What do you mean by "I know where but don't know how `/etc/init.d/transmission`"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't change the daemon to run as root. Change the permissions on the folder where your daemon has to write so that it is allowed to do so.

Assuming it's running as user `transmission`, run something like this as root:

```
chown transmission /mnt/data/torrents/downloads
chmod u+rw /mnt/data/torrents/downloads
```

Comment: thanks @Mat for your response, i have tried it but results in same error.

Comment: please edit your question to state what user the daemon is running as, and the permissions on your directory

Comment: ok i will as soon i get that info

Comment: how did you manage to try what I posted without that info?

Comment: i am not a linux guru but i know some basics of chmod, so tried it earlier but it did not worked.

Comment: my point: you're saying you've tried. Your trying requires that you know which user the service is running as, and what permissions are set on the directory. Why don't you just edit your post with that information?

Comment: sorry @Mat we misunderstood each other, i did not tried the solution you provided yet because i messed up with my installation before you suggested the solution and i will of-course try it because i don't have any other solution. My point was that i chmod777 that folder by connecting through proftp earlier, but it did not worked.

Comment: Hi @Mat, after reinstalling the optware and transmission i did not faced that problem. It just worked may be due to newer version of software or something else. I was not able to test your answer, either way thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl status transmission-daemon

● transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-05-30 15:31:01 EDT; 7min ago
```